# How to format Date in Content Query Web Part?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, date-time

I have a CQWP in which I am querying the data from a document library. ItemStyle being used is  "Title and Description" `Title` displays the title of the Document and the in `Description` I have given a site column name `DateTime` which is of type Date and Time.

The output shows following web part :
[image]

In the description I want to make the date format `DD:MM:YYYY`.

How is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use an additional XSL schema called ddwrt.

Here is a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx) with a good and simple walk-through

> `<xsl:value-of select="@ArticleStartDate"/>` 
> You get back a pretty nasty
> looking result 2009-03-23 00:00:00
>
> However if you use the “FormatDate” function, you can make this look a lot better.
> `<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 2057, 3)"/>`
> Results in this 23 March 2009

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I need still one suggestion, will there be any difference to apply this xsl to SP-2013?

Comment: @users1100 No not at all. It's the some in all versions of SharePoint