# Format Date in Content Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, date-time, formatting, date-format

I have looked through too many threads about this and have made no progress.

So far the following links have helped me the most:

[Content Query WebPart & Date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110157/content-query-webpart-date)

[How to format Date in Content Query Web Part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77000/how-to-format-date-in-content-query-web-part)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx

I am still not getting the date to format though. I think it is just that I don't know where exactly to place the appropriate code.

I am putting the Date I need formatted in the Description field of the Presentation but the description will not always have a date so I cannot change the default (or can I?). I added the TitleDate template from the first link and then edited a line in it to the following:

`<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@TaskDueDate, 1033, 3)" />`

Thank you in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if user typed the date in the description field, then SP will treat that as text and display it as it was typed (Or) are you manipulating the description field to show date from some other field? may be I am not understanding the question!

Answer (score 0):

If the date you are trying to format is part of a string value with other than just a date, you cannot change it.

I.e. if you're `@Description` field contains a string like "This is my string with a date 06/11/2016 that I want changed to Sunday, November 2016" then you cannot change the date format.

The example you mention that you've copied, that just applies the format change on a separate field which only contains a date and then inserts that separately in the template.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it did help me reevaluate how I was using the code. The code is working correctly, I just had the incorrect ItemStyle selected. I appreciate both your time for responding to this question.